# how to access web application using customize URL instead of actual URL?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, amazon-route53

I have created AWS EC2 instance and deploy spring web application in wildfly server under EC2 instance,then bought route53 domain. Domain is mapped to IP of EC2 instance and is working file either using domain name or IP address.
    Example Domain Name :- "ranjitsoni.in"
    Application Context :- /rb
    I have configured redirect setting from  ranjitsoni.in to ranjitsoni.in/rb to access application on path /opt/wildfly/welcome-content/index.html in wildfly server as given below.

```
**<html>
<head>
        <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=rb">
</head>
</html>**

when i hit url ranjitsoni.in, it redirect to ranjitsoni.in/rb.
i want to access initail webpage only with ranjitsoni.in, don't want to display ranjitsoni.in/rb initial.

Please help and Thanks in Advance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the EC2 IP to either any type of AWS Load Balancer or an EIP, as the Public IP can change on an EC2 instance if rebooted for any reason.

There are several options for you to do the redirect. [Cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomRedirects), A proxy like HAProxy, [S3 redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) or do it in the Application code.